# Emulador do Android não roda no Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: hyper-v

estou rodando um Windows Server 2012 R2 no Hyper-V e instalei o VS 2015 Community. Estou tentando rodar uma aplicação básica do android, mas, quando o emulador começa a rodar, aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine ('Nome da VM Android') because one of the Hyper-V components is not running (Virtual machine ID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a declaração abaixo em um [blog](https://charbelnemnom.com/2015/05/is-hyper-v-vnext-going-to-support-nested-virtualization-hyperv-containers-windowsserver/) de um mvp de hyper-v. Ela diz que o hyper-v que executa as máquinas virtuais só pode rodar em máquinas fisicas, ou seja, não funciona em ambientes virtualizados. O que é o meu caso.

> Until today, Windows server Hyper-V could only run Virtual Machines when Hyper-V is enable and running on a physical hardware.